# has_many :through is only working in one direction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, has-many-through, has-many

I have the following has_many :through situation:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :term_enrollments, foreign_key: 'builder_id'
  has_many :terms, through: :term_enrollments
end

class TermEnrollment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :term
  belongs_to :builder, class_name: 'User'
end

class Term < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :builder_term_enrollments, class_name: 'TermEnrollment', foreign_key: 'builder_id'
    has_many :builders, through: :builder_term_enrollments, source: :builder
end
```

The following succesfully creates a term_enrollment:

```
u = User.first
t = Term.first
u.terms << t
```

I can then run `u.terms` succesfully.  The problem is if I run `t.builders`, i get an empty association:

```
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

I'm pretty sure I'm using `source` incorrectly but I'm not sure how.  How do I fix this?

Comment: I'm reasonably sure you're after `inverse_of`, not `source`, to have both ends of the association populated

Answer (score 0):

Could you try setting the foreign key in `:builder_term_enrollments` to `'term_id'` or `:term_id`?

That will enable ActiveRecord to find any rows which have the corresponding term_id.

Answer (score 0):

rewriting the term model fixed it:

```
class Term < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :builder_term_enrollments, class_name: 'TermEnrollment', source: :builder
    has_many :builders, through: :builder_term_enrollments
end
```